# Embedding LuaJIT in Java

Tags: lua, luajit, luajava

If I wanted to embed a normal Lua script in Java, I'd use LuaJ. However, I need to find a way to embed scripts which use LuaJIT's FFI library. One option would be to use LuaJava, but it doesn't appear to be maintained anymore. Any alternatives? I "just" need a way to pass Java primitive types (and ideally arrays) as arguments to LuaJIT functions and get the results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's [Jua](https://github.com/nondev/jua) but it's 32-bit only and not really mature. Probably it's possible to fork it and polish a bit.

Comment: Thanks, seems worth looking into.